# How to count the number for each day from range date

Tags: pandas, dataframe

How to count the number of members in regular status for each day & each department in Jan.
A person is in regular status between regular_date and leave_date.
A dataframe records the entry_date,regular_date,leave_date of every employee.
All dates fillna() with '2100-01-01'.

I tried calulating by loops but it takes a long time when calculating a large amount of data.
Is there any efficient method?

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
columns = ['entry_date', 'leave_date',
           'employee_id', 'department_id', 'regular_date']
data = [['2023-01-01', '2100-01-01', '1', 'a', '2023-01-05'],
        ['2023-01-03', '2023-01-15', '2', 'a', '2023-01-06'],
        ['2023-01-03', '2023-01-18', '3', 'b', '2023-01-08'],
        ['2023-01-08', '2023-01-20', '4', 'b', '2023-01-10']
        ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
date_start = datetime.datetime.strptime('2023-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d')
date_end = datetime.datetime.strptime('2023-01-31', '%Y-%m-%d')
df_lst = []
for x in df['department_id'].unique():
    date_lst = []
    for i in range(int((date_end - date_start).days) + 1):
        day0 = (date_start + datetime.timedelta(i)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        cnt_regular = df[(df['entry_date'] <= day0)
                        & (df['leave_date'] > day0)
                        & (df['regular_date'] <= day0)
                        & (df['department_id'] == x)
                        ].shape[0]
        date_lst.append([day0, x, cnt_regular])
    df_lst.append(pd.DataFrame(date_lst, columns=[
                  'date', 'department_id', 'cnt_regular']))

df_result = pd.concat(df_lst)
df_result['month'] = df_result['date'].apply(lambda x: x[0:7])
df_result['day'] = df_result['date'].apply(lambda x: x[8:10])
df_result.pivot_table(index=['department_id', 'month'], columns=[
                      'day'], aggfunc='sum').reset_index()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Also using numpy broadcasting, you can do:

```
# Convert as DatetimeIndex if necessary
df['entry_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['entry_date'])
df['leave_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['leave_date'])
df['regular_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['regular_date'])

# All days of January (1 -> 31)
month = pd.date_range(date_start, date_end, freq='D').day.values
month_name = date_start.strftime('%Y-%m')

def calendar(df):
    start = np.sum(df['start'].values[:, None] <= month, axis=0)
    end = np.sum(df['end'].values[:, None] <= month, axis=0)
    return (pd.DataFrame(start - end, index=month).T
              .assign(month=month_name).set_index('month'))
    
# Clip dates to be between date_start and end_start (for Jan)
out = (df.assign(start=df['regular_date'].clip(date_start, date_end).dt.day,
                 end=df['leave_date'].clip(date_start, date_end).dt.day)
         .groupby('department_id').apply(calendar).reset_index())
```

Output:

```
>>> out
  department_id    month  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31
0             a  2023-01  0  0  0  0  1  2  2  2  2   2   2   2   2   2   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0
1             b  2023-01  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy broadcasting per groups for count matched values per ranges by [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html):

```
date_start = datetime.datetime.strptime('2023-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d')
date_end = datetime.datetime.strptime('2023-01-31', '%Y-%m-%d')

#defined range of datetimes - not necessary only one month
r = pd.date_range(date_start, date_end, freq='D')

#convert columns to datetimes
cols = ['entry_date','leave_date','regular_date']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pd.to_datetime)

#get count by numpy broadcasting
def f(x):
    r1 = r.to_numpy()[:, None]
    m = ((x['entry_date'].to_numpy() <= r1) &
         (x['leave_date'].to_numpy()  > r1) & 
         (x['regular_date'].to_numpy() <= r1))
    
    #create MulitIndex by `YYYY-MM` and days
    mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([r.strftime('%Y-%m'), r.day])
    return pd.Series(np.sum(m, axis=1), index=mux)

#get values per groups with reshape by stack
out = (df.groupby('department_id').apply(f)
        .stack(0)
        .fillna(0)
        .astype(int)
        .rename_axis(['department_id','month'])
        .reset_index())
```

---

```
print (out)
  department_id    month  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  \
0             a  2023-01  0  0  0  0  1  2  2  2  2   2   2   2   2   2   1   
1             b  2023-01  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1   2   2   2   2   2   2   

   16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  
0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1  
1   2   2   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an inequality join, and can be solved efficiently with [conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/)

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
# you could get more perf
# with the latest improvements in dev
# that means installing directly from github
# pip install git+https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor.git

import pandas as pd
import janitor

# Convert as DatetimeIndex if necessary
df['entry_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['entry_date'])
df['leave_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['leave_date'])
df['regular_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['regular_date'])
month = pd.date_range(date_start, date_end, freq='D')
month = pd.Series(month, name = 'month')

(df
.conditional_join(
    month, 
    # column from the left, column from the right, comparator
    ('entry_date', 'month', '<='), 
    ('leave_date', 'month', '>'), 
    ('regular_date', 'month', '<='),
    # depending on the data size, 
    # you may get more performance with numba
    use_numba = False,
    )
.assign(
    day = lambda f: f.month.dt.day, 
    month = lambda f: f.month.dt.to_period("M"))
.pivot_table(
    index = ['department_id', 'month'], 
    columns = 'day', 
    aggfunc = 'size')
.reindex(columns = range(1,32))
.fillna(0, downcast='infer')
)
day                    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31
department_id month                                                                                                                              
a             2023-01   0   0   0   0   1   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
b             2023-01   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```